# Database of chemicals with associated properties?

Tags: database, parsing, pubchem

I think pubchem has what I need here, I want a database that is -or could be converted into- a table of chemical identifier : series of properties for a school project.
The issue is, pubchem is too large, the only file they offer that I know how to decode is XML (they also offer SDF and ASN, heres the link: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/Substance/CURRENT-Full/), and I don't have enough RAM to open the XMLs in a text editor.

*Is there an alternative database I can use?*

*Is there a way to slice up the XML files into more manageable pieces before loading them?*

Once I have the data in any openable form I will be able to parse it with code, so the data being too much to read through is not an issue.

Comment: Why can't you parse it with code now? You don't have to load the entire file at once.

Comment: how do I not load the full file at once?

Comment: to be specifc, in python, when i call "open" it loads the whole file to RAM, do I need to split the file up on my hard drive or is their another method? Sorry if I didn't phrase my original question very well

Comment: There are many ways to process XML as a stream; if you’re targeting a specific language you should tag the question appropriately so you get specific approaches.

Comment: I think that's the line of questioning i need for google to take me the rest of the way,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think im starting to figure out how to do this. XML stream was a good keyword to search around with. Sorry my phrasing was a little strange in the question, I wasn't really sure what I was asking from a technical standpoint.